# can i use RALLY REST API for accessing Sandbox environment?

Tags: rally

I was given the task to update some workspace in Rally using JAVA REST API. I want to do it in the Sandbox environment first. However, it says that Sandbox does not support API Key. Can someone share how to login to Sandbox using REST? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From:

```
https://help.rallydev.com/rally-application-manager
```

Under "Work Item connector APIKeys limitations":

```
....
APIKeys are not supported in the sandbox environment.
....
```

Comment: hi JPKole, thanks for the comment. Any suggestion on how to approach it otherwise?

Comment: the only other option is to use basic auth.  can you use the constructor that takes a username and password instead?

Comment: hi Kyle. The REST Api for JAVA has deprecated that. Now, it uses only api key. But for .NET it still has that kind of constructor. I am a java developer.